# Upgrading my Schwinn

Tags: mountain-bike, crankset, derailleur-rear

I know I probably should not [upgrade my Schwinn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P47088I), but I have had it for a year and a half, got it from Walmart and no problems.

I want to upgrade the parts on this the bottom bracket, the cranks and the rear derailleur, but I'm not sure what parts are compatible and what is better than the parts that are on it.

I think it has a Shimano Tourney set, but I want to upgrade this to use it as a learning experience. I want to learn how to put certain parts on, so if a problem ever does arise, then I know what to do. But it is a great bike.

People have said that Schwinns suck. I got this for my birthday and it is amazing, but with better parts it can be better. So if anyone has some links to parts that can go on this, post them.

Comment: Don't bother.  Its not a bike that is worth upgrading.  Instead, put your money aside and save up for a much better bike.   Sorry.

Comment: I'm not asking if i should upgrade i am asking what Bette rparts that fit can fit this bike mainly the crank the the rear derailleur the bike doesn't NEED to be upgrade there have been no problems with the bike whatsoever i do not want a new bike i want to get new parts so i can learn how to put new parts on a bike, so in the future maybe 20 years from when i do get a much more expensive specialized bike

Comment: I am not looking for to buy a better bike this one already works wonders and i said this in the paragraph i want to do this so i can learn how to work with a bike a bit hands on stuff so i learn how to do this myself so if there is ever a dent (not literally) then i get replace it fix it thought the bike doesn't need to have any replaced parts people said this bike wouldn't even last me 6 months i had this for a year and a half and i love it i work on this bike quite hard on the trails

Comment: The first thing I'd upgrade is your keyboard. It seems your punctuation keys have worn out. ;) But seriously, some punctuation in both your question and the comments would help your question a great deal.

Comment: Yes i agree thinking about switching back to my google keyboard or just going to my laptop so i can space things better

Comment: So i am guessing everyone will just say buy another bike when i have a perfectly good and working bike

Comment: You need lots of reading, measurement and etc preparation before start this project. Do check out Sheldon Brown site  http://www.sheldonbrown.com/ . You will learn that many parts are not interchangeable unless you know what you are looking, and tools are not cheap either. Changing part properly need lots of practice, and it is not recommended to do this on a working bike unless something broke.

Comment: You don't mention on what riding style you do.  Are you commuting, mountain biking, leisure?

Comment: @joey I think there is plenty of Q&A on this site to cover yours.  I have a earlier model of that bike, but I only upgrade when it breaks.  If you want to discuss it indepth, then it should be taken to the chat page.

Comment: I don't want to upgrade it to have better performing parts it says i that paragraph to learn how to do bike maintenance so when i do need to repair my bike i know a guy here already answered my question he said it was a valid reason i don't want to upgrade to upgrade

Answer (score 1):

You say you want to learn bike maintenance. This is a very valid reason, and what you learn will pay what it costs many times over. I do however caution doing so on your current bike if it running well.

Generally 'If it ain't broke, don't fix it' is a good way to think about bikes upgrades. Upgrading a bike bit by bit is slow and expensive. Presuming everything is in good working order, the problem is that no one component will offer a noticeable improvement. Aside form regular maintenance, if you are patient enough, waiting till bits worn out or broken is the prudent way to learn.

If you want to speed up the process, a better way to learn would be buy (or beg) a doer upper, and play with that. Start with one that seems to mostly work OK, and remove/strip/clean parts, replacing things like cables and chains as you go. Be careful not to spend too much on components though. An alternate would be start with a bare frame, and build a bike from bits. The compatibility issues will likely leave you with several boxes of leftover bits, but you will learn a lot.

You will need a toolkit suitable for bikes- cheap ones that are adequate enough are available on EBay and Amazon and the like.  They have most of the tools needed to work on most bikes.

Comment: Would getting a specialized brand bike and fixing that up be worth it?

Comment: Price for components i don't really care about but if i did want to add upgrades to my current bke do you have reccomondations or would almost anything fit on it its just a matter of what part is higher quality compared to to another such deore vs tourney